# angular 5 httpclient , on post , the response does not return headers, only returns response object

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I recently moved to angular 5 and earlier the http.post was returning the response objecta s complete with headers however using httpclient , it does not return the response headers. How can i change this part of the post code to provide the complete response object including response headers

I read about  using {observable: "response"} , but its not working

```
post(inURL,  data, config = undefined)  {
  let headers, options;
  if (config) {
    options = config;
  } else {
    //headers = this.getDefaultHeader();
    //options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    options = httpOptions;
  }

  let action = this.httpService.post(inURL,  data, options);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    action.subscribe(
      response => resolve(response),
      error => {
        this.interceptError(error);
        reject(error);
      }
    );
  });    
}
```

Comment: It's `{observe: ... }`, not `{observable: ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a very strong reason to return a `promise` instead of an Observable from here.

That being said, you're complicating things here. You could have simply called `toPromise()` on the return value from `post`.

And well, you said that you used `{observable: "response"}` but it didn't work. That's because you didn't use it correctly. It **SHOULD BE** `{observe: "response"}` and **NOT** `{observable: "response"}`

It must be a part of the options. So I've used the spread operator(`...`) and added `{observe: "response"}` to `options`.

Give this a try:

```
post(inURL,  data, config = undefined)  {
  let headers, options;
  if (config) {
    options = config;
  } else {
    //headers = this.getDefaultHeader();
    //options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    options = httpOptions;
  }

  options = { ...options, observe: 'response' };

  this.httpService.post(inURL, data, options)
    .toPromise();
}
```

Comment: You repeated OP's typo everywhere except for in your code.

Comment: @IngoBürk, copy paste, I guess. I've fixed it now BTW :)

Comment: @SiddAjmera thanks , that works , however i am trying to retrive a custom token from the response of a post , but with this , i still dont see the header object having the key    I am looking for ' xxxtoken' which the response header has , however the returned header does not provide access to this xxxtoken key

Comment: @looneytunes, you might want to check if the API actually returns such a header, probably in Postman.

Comment: yes it does  return , cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-security-policy: default-src 'self';font-src 'self' data:;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';frame-ancestors 'none'
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
xxxtoken: e33e8be9-cd14-4114-8bcf-adee60e8fc14
set-cookie: JSESSIONID=CED04E7652F8B31DBAFF7AB041330F33; Path=/view-vlsi; Secure; HttpOnly
status: 200
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000

Answer (score -1):

You can just return the HttpClient reponse after making the HTTP call:

```
getServiceData(): Observable<any>{
      return this.httpClient
        .post(myUrl, requestBodyObj)
        .map((httpResponse: any) => {
            if (httpResponse.operationStatus.statusCode === '0') {
                return httpResponse.data;
            } else {
                throw new Error('error in service call');
            }
        })

 }
```

In your component class you can subscribe to the service method:

```
myService.subscribe( (data) => {
      // do something with data received
    }, error => {
      // do something when error 
    })
```

More details on HttpClient usage can be [seen here](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request) at official guide